# Can you help me about sql?

Tags: sql

I don't understand what this means:

> The enterprise database contains the following relations:
>
> ```
> EMP(eid:integer, ename:string. age:integer, salary:real)
>
> WORKS(eid:integer, did:integer, pct_time:integer)
>
> DEPT(did:integer, dname:string, budget:real, managerid:integer)
> ```
>
> Explain how you would create the DEPT relation in SQL so that every department is guaranteed to have a manager.

Comment: Sounds like you need to consult whatever text book you're meant to be learning from and look up *Constraints*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of this question (which I assume is homework) is to teach you about constraints.

Constraints in database make the DBMS engine assure some properties of the data.
In your case - a foreign key will assure that each record in DEPT that has a manager, the manager actually exists in the EMP table.

Please read about Foreign Keys, Primary Keys, and not null - and be more specific in a following question if something is still unclear.

I am intentionally not adding a link to explanation about those because it should be easy to find..